# Laravel 5: Prevent redirection when the url ends with “/”

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

My application url is:

```
http://localhost/my-app
```

And my admin panel is here:

```
http://localhost/my-app/admin
```

But when I try to access the admin panel using this url:

```
http://localhost/my-app/admin/
```

It redirects me to :

```
http://localhost/admin
```

Is there any way to prevent this by happening? I want to access the admin panel from this url also.

My htaccess file looks like this currently:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Ps. I deleted the "# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder..." lines but it still does not work..I restarted the wamp also.

Comment: Have you tried adding `RewriteBase /my-app` after `RewriteEngine On`?

Comment: But you got no subdirectory in your production environment. So it should be working, or isn't it?

Comment: Tim looks to be correct here. When you say "it still does not work" after removing the trailing slashes rewrite rule, what exactly does that mean? Does it still redirect to "/admin" or does it send you somewhere else?

Comment: It still redirect to "/admin"

Comment: But isn't that the correct behavior in production? I can understand if that's wrong on your localhost, but in production you have no subdirectory or have you?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot give comment, so i'll try here instead.

you need to remove this line from .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

or add # in front of it to comment.